# Why javax.annotation pacakge dose not have type annotations in jdk 8?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotations

I'm try to run some code from the internet which uses type annotations with Intellij IDEA, thelanguage level and JDK is java 8:
  [problem snap shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PV2JQ.png)
the javax.annotation package dose exist yet the type annotations can not be imported, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the jar that contains this class. Add FindBugs to your pom.xml/ your classpath.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
    <artifactId>findbugs</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```